# A basic doubt on sigma algebra generated by a random variable

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

Why do we need the concept of sigma algebra generated by a random variable ?

Answer (score 1):

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mu)$ be a probability space.There is a natural definition of independence of two $\sigma$-sub-algebras $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ of $\mathcal F$, namely 
$$\forall A\in\mathcal A,B\in\mathcal B, \quad \mu(A\cap B)=\mu(A)\mu(B).$$

Now we wood like to formalize the fact that "a realization of the random variable $Y$ does not affect one of $X$", and this is done defining "$X$ is independent of $Y$" if and only if the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $X$ is independent of those of $Y$.